# Angular fetch posts isn't working after mongoose is configured with mongodb

Tags: angular, mongodb

I've installed mongoose and mongodb and I'm trying to fetch posts.  something isn't going right. I am connecting to the database, but I can't figure it out after i try to submit a booking.  I"m including my app.js file and my post.js file below.  I'm using a general find, but i'm afraid I'm getting confused by Post and app.js post model and my booking model. perhaps i'm confusing some of the names.  i'm not sure as I'm lost.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Post = require('./models/post')

const app = express();
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://john:jdhdhdhsh@cluster0-yusts.mongodb.net/node-angular?retryWrites=true")
.then (() => {
  console.log('connected to db')
})
.catch(() => {
  console.log('connection failed');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
  next();
});

app.post("/api/bookings", (req, res, next) => {
  const booking = new Post({
    bookingDate: req.body.bookingDate,
    agent: req.body.agent,
    agentDepartment: req.body.agentDepartment,
    clientName: req.body.clientName,
    projectTitle: req.body.projectTitle,
    clientService: req.body.clientService,
    rate: req.body.rate,
    perDiem: req.body.perDiem,
    startDate: req.body.startDate,
    endDate: req.body.endDate,
    numberOfEpisodes: req.body.numberOfEpisodes,
    numberOfDays: req.body.numberOfDays,
    credit: req.body.credit,
    location: req.body.location,
    travel: req.body.travel,
    dressingRoom: req.body.dressingRoom,
    lodging: req.body.lodging,
    exclusivity: req.body.exclusivity,
    bumps: req.body.bumps,
    options: req.body.options,
    buyer: req.body.buyer,
    buyerType: req.body.buyerType,
    productionCompany: req.body.productionCompany,
    network: req.body.network,
    accountingName: req.body.accountingName,
    accountingEmail: req.body.accountingEmail,
    notes: req.body.notes
  });
  post.save();
  res.status(201).json({
    message: 'Booking added succesfully!'
  });
});

app.get('/api/bookings',(req, res, next) => {
  Post.find().then(documents => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'booking fetched successfully!',
      posts: documents
    });
  });
});

module.exports = app;



const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  bookingDate: {type: Date, required: true },
    agent: {type: String, required: true },
    agentDepartment: {type: String, required: true },
    clientName: {type: String, required: true },
    projectTitle: {type: String, required: true },
    clientService: {type: String, required: true },
    rate: {type: String, required: true },
    perDiem: {type: String },
    startDate: {type: Date },
    endDate: {type: Date },
    numberOfEpisodes: {type: String },
    numberOfDays: {type: String },
    credit: {type: String },
    location: {type: String },
    travel: {type: String },
    dressingRoom: {type: String },
    lodging: {type: String },
    exclusivity: {type: String },
    bumps: {type: String },
    options: {type: String },
    buyer: {type: String },
    buyerType: {type: String },
    productionCompany: {type: String },
    network: {type: String },
    accountingName: {type: String },
    accountingEmail: {type: String },
    notes: {type: String, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Comment: Maybe that’s not your password, but if it is, I’m sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thank you Ben, not my password anymore, and its a dummy db anyway.

Comment: It’s my pleasure.

Comment: Also, you should probably post any error messages you’re getting, or where exactly you’re seeing/not seeing unexpected data show up. That will invite responses.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!
i swapped out booking for post.  I was using the wrong naming convention because i was following a tutorial.  duh.

this was incorrect:  const booking = new Post({
it should've been: const booking = new Booking({